# Edit the [apache-hudi] excerpt

Tags: discussion, tags

I do not have enough experience and based on that, I have two questions about the tag `[apache-hudi]`:

1. I saw an empty excerpt for the `[apache-hudi]` and I tried to update it. Is this brief description fine and enough (thanks for help)?

   > Apache Hudi is a transactional data lake platform with a focus on
   > batch and event processing (with ACID support). Use this tag for
   > questions specific to problems with Apache-Hudi. Do not use this tag
   > for common issues with topic data lake or delta lake.
2. I checked the history for this tag and probably the tag was created by the Stack Overflow Community Bot. Is it correct that the Bot created an empty tag without a description? Do you see added value for this empty tag (it can be a highlight for an expected community update or ...)?

Comment: "I checked history for this tag and probably the tag was created by StackOverflow Community Bot. Is it correct that the Bot created empty tag without description" - Sort of, but not really. When a tag wiki is created by a <20k user, Community takes ownership of the first revision. This isn't the case when a >20k user makes the first edit, but [that wasn't the case](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62092082/revisions). Community didn't make the tag, it just initialised the tag wiki with empty content when an edit was made

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine, I was my expectation, thx